# Can I build a split slider using slick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Animation]

I'm trying to build a slider, I normally use slick slider but that slide the whole content, I'm trying to do a split slider. A little difficult to explain so I animated the idea.

Can I do this using slick? I there another plugin that I could use?

Thanks in advance!!

Edit: Found this CodePen that I can use
Thanks

Comment: There are many ways to do it. For this kind of project, i personnally use GSAP, it's powerful and simple to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Swiper [click here](http://idangero.us/swiper/)

This is the best slider plug-in I've ever used